# Meteor serial flow to to template loading

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, meteor

I am trying to implement an idea I have but I do not have enough experience to figure out which is the best way to go about it. I have a template like:

```
<template name="Example">
<header>
    {{>MainHeader}}
</header>
<main>
     {{>Template.dynamic template=content}}
     {{>Template.dynamic template=subContent}}
</main>
<footer class="page-footer">
    {{>Footer}}
</footer>
</template>
```

And I have a Part A and Part B of a course. Within each part (A & B) there are three parts: 1) watch a video, 2) do a test, 3) do another test. Each part follows that same order.

Each one of the steps (video, test, test) are loaded into main serially, so when you finish watching the video you press next and it then loads the next test into

```
   {{>Template.dynamic template=content}}
```

Let's say I complete each of those steps in part A, then move on to part B.

**My question is: what is the best way to link these steps together efficiently? Or, how do I store the info from Part A video so the next test has access to it?**

I was reading something about linked lists which looks like something I could use but I was not sure how to implement that, as in, is that info saved in the db and then loaded, or should I use something like a `xml` or `json` file?

I just don't want to have to have code a dozen pages when I'm able to use one template much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Meteor way to do it would be to ensure that data is saved to the database and each template would subscribe to the data it needed.

When someone is going through the courseware, I assume you want to keep state of where they are. This state should be in the database. What if they quit the browser between A and B? Upon relaunch, the app should know that (because it knows who they are and can retrieve that state) and present them with B.

You're not required to handle all this with dynamic templates, as you've done. It's hard to know from the details you've provided, but it might also be viable to handle the steps in a single template, controlled by ReactiveVars and helpers. e.g.

```
<template name="A">
    {{#if showVideo}}
        {{> VideoStep testId=getTestId}}
    {{#else}}
        {{#if showTest}}
          {{> TestStep testId=getTestId}}
        {{#else}}
          {{> AnotherTestStep testId=getTestId}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

(... where getTestId() is a helper providing the test id so the other templates can set their state)

don't worry about efficiency at this stage. get it working w/ publishes and subscribes. be thoughtful about your database structure. use Meteor methods to save your state to the db.

Comment: Hey Zim thanks alot for your help that seem like the perfect way to do it. You are right not to think about efficiency at this stage, its always seem to be somethings that holds be back. Thanks